# How to determine the vector space of polynomials?

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials, vector-spaces

I need to determine the vector space of a polynomial spanned by B. So B = {1+x, 1-x, 1+x<sup>3</sup>, 1-x<sup>3</sup>} and I need to find the dimension of this vector space. The answer says the dimension is 3 but I don't know how you get to that answer.

Answer (score 1):

Note that $1+x = -(1-x) + (1+x^3) + (1-x^3) $. The set is linearly dependent. Removing 1+x results in a linearly independent list, which is easy to show.

Answer (score 0):

The dimension is 3 because any linear combination of these polynomials can only give you up to x^3. Intuitively it makes sense, but we have to show that we can express any Ax^3+Bx^2+Cx+D as a linear combination of the other three, that I leave it up to you.